# Selenium+Python Разрешить уведомления в Firefox

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

есть такой вопрос как реализовать чтобы Selenium разрешал в таком случае [image: нужно чтобы нажимало Разрешить]
<sub>(источник: [mozilla.net](https://prod-cdn.sumo.mozilla.net/uploads/gallery/images/2017-10-18-05-45-38-20e1d7.png))</sub>

желательно надо чтобы он нажимал сам буду очень благодарен

Comment: Я могу ошибаться но по моему, такие ситуации обрабатывать самим селениумом невозможно (потому что это интерфейс самого браузера), а настройками профиля (что в Хроме, что в Лисе) можно только отключить такие уведомления

Comment: @Kota, Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Answer (score 0):

Используйте скрипт [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) для нажатия на кнопку разрешения уведомлений.

[Вот](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/) одна из статей, описывающая технологию, на несколько другом примере, но применимая и здесь.

1. Устанавливаем AutoIt и редактор скриптов.
2. Открываем сайт Селениумом (чтобы был чистый профиль), дожидаемся запроса на разрешение нотификаций.
3. Создаем AutoIt скрипт, находящий окно браузера и нажимающий кнопку "Разрешить".
4. Компилируем AutoIt скрипт в исполняемый файл.
5. Вставляем выполнение скрипта в проект с Селениумом.
6. Профит!